# How can I store tile maps as PNG images?

Tags: java, tilemap, image, file-format

I want to let players of my top-down game save, load and share worlds as PNG images. How do I read the colors in a PNG file or change them?

I imagine something like this:

```
BufferedImage mapImg = ImageLoader.loadImage(path);

// (then, later)

for(x = 0; x < mapImg.width; x++) {
    for(y = 0; y < mapImg.height; y++) {
        // Look up the color at this position
    }
}
```

Here is my ImageLoader class:

```
public class ImageLoader {

    public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path) {
            try {
                return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(path));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                 System.exit(1);
            }
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What engine or libraries are you using? We have [a question about doing this in Slick2D](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/74589/in-slick2d-how-can-i-generate-a-2d-platformer-map-from-an-image?rq=1) that you might find useful.

Answer (score 1):

That is right idea for reading/writing images but you'll want to get your "ImageLoader" class from a library, which will then give you a regular bitmap in memory to work with. The layout of that bitmap class is going to depend on the library you use.

To see why, or what you need to handle if you want to write your own, see the [W3C PNG Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/).

Comment: Here is the code from that class... I'm not quite sure what you mean @jzx *Sorry for stupid*                                       `public class ImageLoader {
 
 public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path){
  try {
   return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(path));
  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   System.exit(1);
  }
  return null;
 }
}`

Comment: @thedobbles You can edit your question to include additional information.